# Pipe group to Set-PnPListItemPermission powershell cmdlet

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell

Following one-liner failed

```
Get-PnPGroup | where-Object {$_.title -eq 'test account'} | Set-PnPListItemPermission -Identity 1 -List "Accounts" -AddRole "Read" -Group $_.id
```

yielding error

```
Set-PnPListItemPermission : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Group' because it is null.
At line:1 char:139
+ ...  "Read" -Group $_.id
+                    ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-PnPListItemPermission], ParameterBindingV 
   alidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,SharePointPnP.Po 
   werShell.Commands.Lists.SetListItemPermission
```

However, by breaking the pipe into 2 commands it works

```
$group = Get-PnPGroup | where-Object {$_.title -eq 'test account'} 
Set-PnPListItemPermission -Identity 1 -List "Accounts" -AddRole "Read" -Group $group.id
```

How to run the command in one pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a foreach-object around Set-PnPListItemPermission

```
Get-PnPGroup | where-Object {$_.title -eq 'test account'} | Foreach-Object {Set-PnPListItemPermission -Identity 1 -List "Accounts" -AddRole "Read" -Group $_.id}
```

But also be aware that the only thing you gain by putting it on one line is:

- Harder to debug
- Slower execution
- Not potentially overwriting variable

Comment: That works. One liner is preferred because in my case the command string is composed from Excel rows and bulk executed. I know I can also write a full-blown ps1 script to parse Excel rows to list and iterate but it's a matter of perception of convenience.